# OSX Yosemite: Can't login to MacBook Air, FileVault is on

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, language, login-screen

I can't get into my Mac (10.10.5 Yosemite). The problem is that I know the password but I simply can't type it in.

Yesterday I bought this laptop, I'm Lithuanian so I decided to make the default language Lithuanian. When Lithuanian language is on, instead of number keys you type in letters. Today, silly me, I decided to change the login password (administrator) and at that time the language my keyboard was typing was English, so I changed the password to `enter123`.

Now, when I try to login to the Mac, I simply can't because the default language is Lithuanian and when I type the password it simply writes in as `enterąčę` instead of `enter123`.

I cannot change the language. I tried recovery mode, my FileVault is on. There's no guest. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you boot into single user mode (Command-S while powering on) and then change the language with `languagesetup ` ?